# Receive " No changes, no records " when creating relationship between 2 nodes

Tags: database, neo4j, data-science

I'm trying to create a relationship between Client and Client Doctor, so here is what i've done:
I tried this first then got "no changes, no records" notice

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Consultation.csv" AS row
MATCH (c:Client), (cd:ClientDoctor)  
WHERE c.Client = row.ClientNum AND cd.CDNum = row.CDNum
CREATE (c)-[Consultation:consults]-(cd)
SET Consultation = row
```

then I tried this way but still receive the same notice:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Consultation.csv" AS row  
MATCH (c:Consultation{ClientNum: row.ClientNum})
MATCH (cd:Consultation {CDNum: row.CDNum})
MERGE (c)-[:is_consulted_by]->(cd);
Set Consultation = row
```

Here is the csv file:
[CSV FIle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etpos.png)
Does anyone know how to fix this problem? please help
Thank you!

Comment: How did you import the original graph?

Comment: Maybe you need to convert your numbers to integers: `toInteger(row.ClientNum)`

Comment: It seems you MATCH clauses don't match anything in the graph, which would be why the subsequent CREATE/MERGE clauses don't run. Double check the label, property case, the property value types, etc

Answer (score 0):

Match and return 1 Client and 1 ClientDoctor to check properties names and types
then Load one row from the file and also check properties names and types matches

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).